# Missing Number in a Seven Segment Circle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, missing-digits

[image: Missing Number in a Seven Segment Circle]

**What number should replace the question mark?**

Please be helpful. If you have the answer, please reply to this post with the explanation and answer. If you don't have the answer, then don't comment. It's simple.

Source: My school's homework.

Comment: Hi Mods:
I just want some clarity before I respond with the answer — are we in the business of answering homework questions like this? I didn’t think we were, but if we are then we can proceed.

Comment: @El-Guest We don't have a policy *per se* on homework, but generally prefer that people looking for homework help to tell us what they've tried and what has/hasn't worked, and then ask specific questions, rather than merely asking for a solution. Also, answers should be geared toward helping the OP find the solution themselves, rather than outright providing the answer. This is to my understanding roughly concurrent with homework policies on other stacks.

Comment: @Rubio thanks very much — will follow that policy going forward. Didn’t know how much to give away so glad that you posted a response. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start at the number 1.

> Now go clockwise around the circle, skipping one spot each time, so that you visit in turn the numbers 1, 2, 4, 7, etc.

You should now be able to find how to fill in the missing value.

Comment: @malkstick Glad you were able to get it now. :)